# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Action hook not triggered on renewal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions, hook-woocommerce

I have made a custom function which adds account funds (£40) to a user's account when their subscription payment is successful.

The problem I have is that the hook doesn't seem to trigger, when the renewell happens the funds are not added to the account.

I enabled debugging in Woocommerce and pushed the renewal manually within the cron management, when I do this the function works and the funds are added to the account.

Here is my function (functions.php);

```
add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_add_funds', 10, 2);

function custom_add_funds($user_id) {

    // get current user's funds
    $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );

    // add £40
    $funds = $funds + 40.00;

    // add funds to user
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
```

----- SOLVED -----

I needed to up the memory limit on wordpress, the IPN url was Fatal Errored/exhausted

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete` hook fires every time a payment is complete, so both a new subscription payment and a renewal will cause it to fire.

I work around this issue with the following code...

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete','my_function');
function my_function($subscription) {

    $last_order = $subscription->get_last_order( 'all', 'any' );

    if ( wcs_order_contains_renewal( $last_order ) ) {
        return;
    } else {

        // Getting the user ID from the current subscription object
        $user_id = get_post_meta($subscription->ID, '_customer_user', true);

        // get current user's funds
        $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );

        // add £40
        $funds += 40;

        // update the funds of the user with the new value
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );
   }

}
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: That doesn't give anything more than my answer is already giving and it doesn't take in account the author's question code.

Comment: This helped me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are also defining two parameters and only accepting 1.  This will also waste memory.

Your code:

```
 add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_add_funds', 10, 2);

 function custom_add_funds($user_id)
 {
 }
```

Change your add_action call from 2 to 1:

```
 add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_add_funds', 10, 1);
```